# iPad Application working in 3.2 but not 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I wrote a program in the 3.2 SDK.  I just upgraded to the new 4.2 SDK today.  I can run the application fine in the 3.2 simulator.  When I switch to the 4.2 simulator, the application crashes right after launching.  I get the following error:

"Failed to load NSMainNibFile MainWindow"

I'm not understanding how this runs fine with 3.2 and not 4.2.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I had this exact thing happen to me. I
>   traced it to a bunch of missing Nib
>   files Target > [App Name] > Copy
>   Bundle resources. The MainWindow.xib
>   file was missing in this directory
>   along with a bunch of other files. I
>   deleted all the nib files from my
>   Resources directory (only the
>   references) and then added the
>   existing files back and everything
>   started working again. It definitely
>   looks like an XCode bug.

from - http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4958-failed-load-nsmainnibfile-mainwindow.html